# How to restore Pycharm Project in windows

Tags: python, windows, pycharm

I am having this extremely weird issue with restoring a pycharm project in pycharm 5 on windows. Originally all I wanted to do is make it so the project does not appear at the start selection, but ultimately that command has translated into something else.

So far I have checked my recycle bin and used recuva but it's no where to be found. Is there some type of default in the pycharm that disables this behavior and if it possible to get my projects back?

Comment: What have you done? Where do you want to 'restore' the project from? If you've started a project, it should be in the recent projects list.

Comment: I have removed it from the recent projects list at start up and that is what caused the original issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you've cleared your recent projects you'll need to locate the folder where you saved your project.

Pycharm stores the individual project config files in a `.idea` directory in the project root, then further files for the general app config in Windows are stored in;

- `<User home>\.PyCharmXX\config` that contains user-specific settings.
- `<User home>\.PyCharmXX\system` that stores PyCharm data caches.

To open your project again, you'll need to point Pycharm's 'open project' dialog to the directory containing the `.idea` folder, so if you can't remember where you saved the project, I'd suggest running a search for `.idea`, remembering that it will likely be a hidden folder.

See the [docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/project-and-ide-settings.html?search=windows%20application%20data) on the application data

Comment: Thanks Mark, I am still not able to get the actually python file restore but I do see how it can restore the project settings.

Comment: @user3263650 what python file do you mean? A project file that you've been working on?

Comment: checked for hidden files, it still wiped it